# react-native-camera freezes app when opened 2 times via navigator

Tags: javascript, ios, camera, react-native

I'm using the https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera library in a view that is contained inside a simple `<Navigator />` component.

Everything works as expected until you navigate back the Home view and try to reload the View with the `<Camera />`. There are no error messages in the console OR in Xcode which makes this extremely hard to pinpoint the problem.

When I delete the entire `<Camera />` component, the navigation works as expected and the view reloads fine.

There is currently an open issue on github https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/80 but as time is of the essence, I am wondering if anyone else has found a solution to this problem and can share a fix.

standard render method:

```
render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.outer}>

            <Overlay
                modalVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
                />

            <Camera
                ref="cam"
                style={styles.container}
                captureTarget={Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
                type={this.state.cameraType}>

                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.circlebutton} onPress={this._takePicture}>
                    <Text>Take Picture</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </Camera>

            <Image
                source={{uri: this.state.imageURI, isStatic:true}}
                style={{width: this.state.imageURI ? 100 : 0, height: this.state.imageURI ? 100 : 0, opacity: this.state.imageURI ? 1 : 0}}
                />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

On Xcode, Go to `RCTCamera.xcodeproj` (This is one of the react native libraries)

In `RCTCameraManager.h`

Add the property
`@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTCamera *camera;`

In `RCTCameraManager.m`

```
- (UIView *)view
{
    return [[RCTCamera alloc] initWithManager:self bridge:self.bridge];
}
```

Replace With:

```
- (UIView *)view
{
    if(!self.camera){
        self.camera = [[RCTCamera alloc] initWithManager:self bridge:self.bridge];
        return self.camera;
    }
    return self.camera;
}
```

Hope thats help.

Comment: You are a genius and a scholar sir.  I would be blessed to work in the same hemisphere as you. It worked.

Comment: How to solve this for android